# Qt “forgets” to link one of my “moc_MyClass.o” objects

Tags: qt

The source file is clearly in the project, among the rest of my classes.

I have Q_OBJECT defined for the class, like the rest of my Qt Classes.

My class compiles with the rest of the classes. Yet, the linker fails on the vtable for the constructor/destructor for my class. Checking the linker command: It seems like the moc_Myclass.cpp is never generated or built. so nothing to link against.

How can that be? why is it left out?

Comment: If you're using qmake, I find this sometimes happens - doing a `make clean && qmake && make` resolves it.

Comment: Which building system are you using (qmake, cmake)? Could you post it?

Comment: Just to check:  you have declared MyClass.h in the HEADERS section of your .pro file, correct?

Comment: Latest Qt-Creator, OSX, qmake. Qt 4.7.4

Comment: yes. cpp and h are in HEADERS and SOURCE sections.

Comment: the moc for MYCLASS is never created! - I can't understand why. It looks just like any other class that DOES get a moc created for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troubling resolution: When I removed the cpp/h file from the projcet, and then added them back in the moc for my class began being generated correctly so link passed.

That's clearly a Qt "project cancer" bug, but at least now I know how to "cure" it.